# Calculating days passed

Tags: stata

I have a variable `date` like this:

[image]

I want to calculate how many days have passed since, say, `Jan 1 of 1960`.

However, this is tedious. Also in some years, February has `28` days.

What I've been trying is basically looking up every single calendar, calculate how many days are there in each year, recognize string like `jan` as month variable `1` and so on.

Is there any short and efficient way to do this?

Comment: No screenshots please. Read [How to create high quality reproducible examples in Stata](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377015).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `daily()` or `date()` function:

```
display date("1/1/2012", "DMY") - date("1/1/1960", "DMY")
18993
```

More generally, if you have a string variable with dates:

```
clear

input str10 date1
"01/01/2012"
"01/01/2011"
"01/01/2014"
"19/12/2014"
end

generate date2 = date(date, "DMY") - date("1/1/1960", "DMY")

list

     +--------------------+
     |      date1   date2 |
     |--------------------|
  1. | 01/01/2012   18993 |
  2. | 01/01/2011   18628 |
  3. | 01/01/2014   19724 |
  4. | 19/12/2014   20076 |
     +--------------------+
```

If the variable containing the dates is numeric:

```
clear

input date1
18993
18628
19724
20076
end

format %tdDD/NN/CCYY date1

generate date2 = date1 - date("1/1/1960", "DMY")
```